# Can anyone identify this battery connector?

Tags: batteries, connector

It's a fairly common sort of connector, I think it's the same one that's used for GoPro batteries and a lot of cameras too, but I can't find out the name of it or where to buy just the connector.

The male part of it is 3 blade prongs.[image: male version]

[image: female version]

I want to build a couple of spare batteries to replace this one rather than pay a rather extortionate OEM rate, but I don't want to cut into the device so I'd like the connector to match.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should probably also add - this is a drone rather than a camera!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this really counts as answer, but I found what I wanted via the revelation that laptop batteries have a similar connector. Ideally I only wanted the female part but at $0.31 a set I can deal with it.
**https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-laptop-battery-connector.html**

Comment: Perfectly good answer, obviously you should measure the pin sizes and spacing to make sure they match up.

Comment: "Sorry, your search ' laptop-battery-connector ' did not match any products. Please try again."